# Maximum Capacity Path Problem with constraints

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, path

I was trying to develop an algorithm for maximum capacity problem with constraints but couldn't figure out the necessary changes required for correct output.
The problem is:
 Given an undirected graph with two parameters (weight,cost). We need to find the [Maximum Capacity path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem#:%7E:text=In%20graph%20algorithms%2C%20the%20widest,the%20maximum%20capacity%20path%20problem.) from source to destination such that the cost of the path(sum of the edges of path) is within a fixed value specified by the user. In other words, it(sum of cost parameter along the path) is upper bounded by a constant value.
I modified the existing algorithm by adding and extra cost constraint while relaxing the edges but was unable to make it work for all types of graph. I was also wondering if this problem is NP-Complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved in polynomial time. For instance, you can use binary search over the weight.  Given a candidate weight, delete all edges with lower weight, then find the lowest-cost path and test whether its cost is below the lower bound; that tells you whether the weight was too high or too low.  Repeat until binary search converges.